# how to filter or extract link elements excluding span and save them in comma separated array using symfony dom crawler?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, xpath, domcrawler

```html
<span class="tl">
<a href="/en/laravel/" class="c">laravel</a>, <span>goutte</span>, <a href="/en/html/">html</a>, <span>dom crawler</span>, <a href="/en/form/">form</a><span>guzzle</span>, <span>web scrapper</span>
</span>
<span class="tl">
<a href="/en/laravel/" class="c">laravel</a>, <span>goutte</span>, <a href="/en/elequent/">elequent</a>, <span>dom crawler</span>, <span>guzzle</span>, <a href="/en/orm/">orm</a>, <span>web scrapper</span>
</span>
<span class="tl">
<a href="/en/laravel/" class="c">laravel</a>, <a href="/en/goutte">goutte</a>, <a href="/en/php/">php</a>, <span>dom crawler</span>, <a href="/en/guzzle">guzzle</a>, <a href="/en/web-scrapper">web scrapper</a>
</span>
```

I want to extract the information in an array like this

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'laravel, html, form' (length=19)
  1 => string 'laravel, elequent, orm' (length=22)
  2 => string 'laravel, goutte, php, guzzle, web scrapper' (length=43)
```

Comment: what do you need to scrape? a tag which is having span tag inside it?

Comment: only the a tag texts not the texts inside span tags separated by comma.

Comment: link text only?

Comment: yes link texts only comma separated.

Comment: @coolsaint According to last index of your expected output it contains `web scrapper` was that a typo because it is contained in span tag

Comment: @SahilGulati You got it right I have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: @coolsaint So you want all the text in `span` and `a` tag, in the all the three span's of your input HTML

Comment: @coolsaint I have updated my post you can check it.

Comment: @SahilGulati not the span text, only a tag texts separated by comma. but I was working on symfony dom crawler.

Comment: @coolsaint I have updated post again can you check

Answer (score 1):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/807127)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string=<<<HTML

<span class="tl">
<a href="/en/laravel/" class="c">laravel</a>, <span>goutte</span>, <a href="/en/html/">html</a>, <span>dom crawler</span>, <a href="/en/form/">form</a><span>guzzle</span>, <span>web scrapper</span>
</span>
<span class="tl">
<a href="/en/laravel/" class="c">laravel</a>, <span>goutte</span>, <a href="/en/elequent/">elequent</a>, <span>dom crawler</span>, <span>guzzle</span>, <a href="/en/orm/">orm</a>, <span>web scrapper</span>
</span>
<span class="tl">
<a href="/en/laravel/" class="c">laravel</a>, <a href="/en/goutte">goutte</a>, <a href="/en/php/">php</a>, <span>dom crawler</span>, <a href="/en/guzzle">guzzle</a>, <span>web scrapper</span>
</span>

HTML;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query('//span[@class="tl"]');
$data=array();
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $tempArray=array();
    $aNodes=$domXPath->query(".//a",$result);
    foreach($aNodes as $aNode)
    {
        if($aNode instanceof DOMElement)
        {
            $tempArray[]=$aNode->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    $data[]=  implode(", ", $tempArray);
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: I was expecting something like this for my symfony dom crawler script 

$links['tag'] = $crawler->filter('span.tl >:not(span)')->each(function ($node) {
       return $node->text();
         });

Comment: @coolsaint what is wrong with my post? can you tell me which thing is missing?

Comment: I believe it solves the problem but in my case I am using crawler object by symfony domcrawler.